# Creating Custom Post Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, post, routes, custom-action

I'm trying to create a a custom post method but i'm having trouble finding how to start.

What I want to do is to be able to read a CSV file, foreach entry, insert a new row into a database.

In the index file, I want to be able to hit 1 link or button to start a custom method.

This method would open my csv file (traverse each row and insert into database)

So essentially on my index.html.erb I would like to see something like:

```
<%= link_to "Load CSV to Database", :controller => MyController, :action => MyCustomAction %>
```

I believe I need to edit my routes.rb and this is where I'm stuck. How do I make it so that my routes know that MyCustomAction is a post.

My Rake Route:

```
use_database_csv_files POST   /csv_files/use_database(.:format) csv_files#use_database
         csv_files GET    /csv_files(.:format)              csv_files#index
                   POST   /csv_files(.:format)              csv_files#create
      new_csv_file GET    /csv_files/new(.:format)          csv_files#new
     edit_csv_file GET    /csv_files/:id/edit(.:format)     csv_files#edit
          csv_file GET    /csv_files/:id(.:format)          csv_files#show
                   PUT    /csv_files/:id(.:format)          csv_files#update
                   DELETE /csv_files/:id(.:format)          csv_files#destroy
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
resources :MyController do
  collection do
    post 'MyCustomAction'
  end
end
```

This [blog post](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/the-lowdown-on-routes-in-rails-3/) may also help you if you want to do `member` instead of `collection`

Comment: Thanks Scott. I've added the collection but now when I click the link, it thinks that the MyCustomAction is and ID for show. Is there another way i'm suppose to generate the link_to?

Comment: You can try the `_path` route. `rake routes` would show the path, e.g. `MyContoller_Action` and you just append `_path`.

Comment: It still says the same thing, it still assumes that i'm trying to access a show method where MyCustomAction is the ID. I appreciate your help Scott!

Comment: Can you post your `rake routes` output?

Comment: use_database_csv_files POST   /csv_files/use_database(.:format) csv_files#use_database
             csv_files GET    /csv_files(.:format)              csv_files#index
                       POST   /csv_files(.:format)              csv_files#create
          new_csv_file GET    /csv_files/new(.:format)          csv_files#new
         edit_csv_file GET    /csv_files/:id/edit(.:format)     csv_files#edit
              csv_file GET    /csv_files/:id(.:format)          csv_files#show

Comment: PUT    /csv_files/:id(.:format)          csv_files#update
                       DELETE /csv_files/:id(.:format)          csv_files#destroy
use_database_csv_files is the custom path that I want to use.

Comment: Hi Scott, I did end up getting it to work. I just had to add a match line in my route and that seems to do the trick. Thanks for you help